# Angular issue with undefined

Tags: angular, undefined

I have been given an issue to look at in an application that I am nor familiar with, angular is not my usual development environment so I don't know what is going on with this piece of code.

The code is to place pins onto a map, there is a map component defined as

```
export class FuseGoogleMapsDocsComponent {
@Input() coordinates = [{ 'lat': -34.397, 'lng': 150.644 }];
@Input() ceterLat = -34.397;
@Input() ceterLng = 150.644;
constructor() {
```

}

There is a HTML tag that references the component
`<fuse-google-maps-docs [ceterLat]="centerLat" [ceterLng]="centerLng" [coordinates]="coordinates"></fuse-google-maps-docs>`

But when the coordinates array is populated the array is always undefined

The array is declared as

```
coordinates = [];
```

And the function that populates the array is: The array returns 39 rows and the loop works successfully but after the push statements, the coordinates array is undefined.

```
public GetIpListMap() {
const DataUrl = 'api/IPTracking/GetUserIPAddress?userID=' + this.userID;
this._http.get(DataUrl).subscribe(response => {
  let maps = response.data;
  let allLat = 0;
  let allLng = 0;
  let i = 0;

  maps.forEach(item => {
    allLat += item.latitude;
    allLng += item.longitude;
   const coordinate = { lat: item.latitude, lng: item.longitude};
    i += 1;


    this.coordinates.push(coordinate);
  });
  this.centerLat = allLat / i;
  this.centerLng = allLng / i;
});
```

}

I am sure this is something really simple but I just cannot seem to work it out.

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are the `coordinates` array defined/updated on the component holding `fuse-google-maps-docs`?

Comment: this.coordinates is an array of objects, e.g. [{lat:0.2,lng:12},{lat:0.2,lng:14}..]. Inside the .ts you referered to the array as **this.** coordinates (The only exception is when you declare de variable -your `coordinates=[]'. But only has value after the this._http.get **has finised**. If you call to the function GetIpListMap(); and inmediatly write console.log(this.coordinates) you see an empy array -if after the map.forEach you write console.log(this.coordinates) you must see the coordinates

Comment: @Eliseo what I was asking is to update the question with the .ts file for the component on which template `<fuse-google-maps-docs [ceterLat]="centerLat" [ceterLng]="centerLng" [coordinates]="coordinates"></fuse-google-maps-docs>` is being used

Comment: It looks like it passes in the coordinates array and is then used by `<p fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
                <agm-map [latitude]="ceterLat" [longitude]="ceterLng">
                    <agm-marker *ngFor="let coordinate of coordinates" [latitude]="coordinate.lat" [longitude]="coordinate.lng"></agm-marker>
                </agm-map>
            </p>`

Comment: @Eliseo - That's the issue I have, after the foreach has completed, the this.coordinates is still undefined. I have checked the data in coordinate and this is being populated correctly

Comment: @Tim it is difficult to help without the typescript code for the component using fuse-google-maps-docs on its template.

Comment: @GCSDC - I don't think the component is the issue as the coordinates array in the page which calls the map component is showing as undefined. But here is the .ts code for the map component.

Comment: @GCSDC Here is the .ts code` `import { Component, OnInit, Input, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
    selector: 'fuse-google-maps-docs',
    templateUrl: './google-maps.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./google-maps.component.scss']
})
export class FuseGoogleMapsDocsComponent {
    @Input() coordinates = [{ 'lat': -34.397, 'lng': 150.644 }];
    @Input() ceterLat = -34.397;
    @Input() ceterLng = 150.644;
    constructor() {
    }
}`

Comment: @GCSDC - it then uses it on the html as ` <div class="my-48">
            <!-- <h2>Sample</h2> -->
            <p fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
                <agm-map [latitude]="ceterLat" [longitude]="ceterLng">
                    <agm-marker *ngFor="let coordinate of coordinates" [latitude]="coordinate.lat" [longitude]="coordinate.lng"></agm-marker>
                </agm-map>
            </p>
        </div>`

Comment: Is the coordinates array getting initialised correctly? It is only defined as coordinates = [];